# Javascript error when a4j button is clicked for more than 20 times no response

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

Friends,

Request your help we are using JSF 1.2 with richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.

I am using simple a4j command button which is performing some action on click of the button and does some rendering. When the similar action is performed for more than 20 times i get a java script error on the page and no action can be performed until i refresh the page.

Javascript Error

---

The system cannot locate the resource specified

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq5mE.jpg)

I have attached the screen shot of the javascript error as well.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="approve"

    value="#{lcBundle.APPROVAL_BUTTON}" style="padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px;"

    action="#{workflowApprovalBean.approve}"

    data="#{workflowApprovalBean.showDialog}"

    oncomplete="showConfirmationDialogBox(data);eventButtons(true);"

    reRender="message,approvalResultForm,searchCriteriaFourth,searchCriteriaFiveth,actionLink"

    disabled="#{(workflowApprovalBean.enablButtons) or (not workflowApprovalBean.disableOFACButton)}" />
```

Thanks 
Tauqeer

Comment: Please reattach the screenshot

Comment: unable to attached a screen, but u can find the URL 
http://localhost:8080/<applicaitoncontext>/a4j/g/3_3_2.GAorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.Ajaxscript.jsf

Comment: that definitively isn't a valid url